# $http call in after another $http call returned unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a piece of code like below

```js
function init() {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: baseUrl + 'service/'+'/serviceA',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': "application/json",
            }
        }).then(function successResponse(response) {
            $scope.result = response.data;
            if ($scope.result) {
                // initB is another $http get method
                initB();
            }
          // initC is another $http get method
            initC();
          // initD is another $http get method
            initD();
        });
    }
```

My unit test like below

```js
describe('Controller: toolbarCtrl', function() {
beforeEach(module('TestApp'));

var $httpBackend, $rootScope, createController,$location;

beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    $location = $injector.get('$location');
    var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

    createController = function() {
        return $controller('toolbarCtrl', {
            '$scope': $rootScope
        });
    };       
}));

afterEach(function() {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});

it("init B", function() {    
        $httpBackend.whenGET(/http:\/\/.*\/serviceA.*/).respond(200, true);
        $httpBackend.whenGET(/http:\/\/.*\/serviceB.*/).respond(200, ["A","B","C"]);
        var controller = createController();
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect($rootScope.B).toBe(["A", "B", "C"]);
    });
```

but it doesn't work, it will throw an exception

> Unsatisfied requests: GET /http://.*/serviceB.*/

if I remove this line `$httpBackend.whenGET(/http:\/\/.*\/serviceB.*/).respond(200, ["A","B","C"]);`

the code will not throw any exception, but B is not inited;

if I remove `$httpBackend.whenGET(/http:\/\/.*\/serviceA.*/).respond(200, true);`

it will throw exception:

> Unexpected request: GET http://localhost:8633/serviceA

Anyone can help?

Comment: you realise you're not "waiting" on initB/initC or initD

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, initB/C/D can be executed in parallel, they don't have any relationship, when the init process completed, I assign the response data to B,C,D variable in the success event handler.

Comment: @Allen4Tech why you want to test the $http method? It's already tested by AngularJS community. You have to create a mock to test that service and mocking mean no real test case. Have a test-case for the function if it contains any logic. I am sure we can write good and meaningful test case without having a mock. I have also written test case with mock for $http and some other services but now I am sure that I am gonna reason out before writing any unit test case.

Comment: @Ajay I don't want to test $http, so I use $httpBackend to mockup the response. in the test case, if I call that service, return me an array, the real code logic will assign the response to B, so I need to test if B equals to the response which I mocked

Comment: @Allen4Tech Can we test that logic separately from the $http request? If we can then we have already tested that code and I think then there is no need to mock $httpBackend.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what the code you have before the "it" function looks like in your test but it looks like you are not instantiating **$httpBackend** (or maybe instantiating it after you instantiate your service/controller). Your test needs to call on **$httpBackend** before the component you are trying to test.

Comment: Can you please still include the whole test code ? At least the part you claim is loading **$httpBackend** before your service/controller.

Comment: Hmmm, looks good, it's weird that it's failing... Could you also add your whole **toolbarCtrl** controller ? Maybe the issue is there.